# How to redirect to top level domain and not relative value

Tags: redirection

Under admin/config/system/site-information, the startpage is configured as /home. So when you go to www.domain.com, the content of /home is displayed. However, when a form is submitted, it automatically redirects to www.domain.com/home. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Any form using ***_form1_submit($form, $form_state) { .....drupal_set_message(...) on the startpage itself

So, in the content of the node /home, there is a form, when submitting that form, it does not redirect to domain.com, but redirects to domain.com/home

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it as follows:

in the form submit handler, I simply added:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
```

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: I love finding solutions to problems I didn't know I had. Nice one :)

Comment: Note [form_state redirect does not work](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074616) on custom forms in D7. You have to use a submit handler to accomplish the redirect.